# Ignore "NaN" in pandas calculations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I made a simple script that goes to the ECF website and searches for players (API calls) and then downloads their latest results. However, one calculation just shows "nan" if any of the column values are "nan".

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 600)

playerurl = "https://www.ecfrating.org.uk/v2/new/api.php?v2/players/name/"
playerfname = input("Enter Player's (approx.) First Name (e.g Joh for John): ")
playerlname = input("Enter Player's (approx.) Last Name (e.g Smi for Smith): ")
URL2 = playerurl+playerfname+"%20"+playerlname

response2 = requests.get(URL2)
data2 = response2.json()
mydata2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2['players'])
mydata2 = mydata2.drop(['member_no','due_date','club_code','nation','nation2','flag','category'], axis=1)
mydata2.rename(columns = {'full_name':'Full_Name', 'club_name':'Club','gender':'Gender','date_last_game':'LastGame'}, inplace = True)
mydata2.index.name = "Row"

print(tabulate(mydata2, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

chooseplayer = input("Choose Row Number: ")
playerID = mydata2.at[int(chooseplayer),'ECF_code']
baseurl = "https://www.ecfrating.org.uk/v2/new/api.php?v2/games/Standard"
howmanygames = input("Enter how many past games you want to see: ")
URL = baseurl+"/player/"+playerID+"/limit/"+howmanygames
response = requests.get(URL)
data = response.json()

mydata = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['games'])
mydata.loc[mydata.score==5,'score']='0.5'
mydata.loc[mydata.colour=="w",'colour']='W'
mydata.loc[mydata.colour=="b",'colour']='B'
mydata = mydata[mydata.opponent_no != 0]
mydata['score'] = pd.to_numeric(mydata['score'],errors='coerce')
mydata['increment'] = pd.to_numeric(mydata['increment'],errors='coerce')
mydata['opponent_rating'] = pd.to_numeric(mydata['opponent_rating'], errors='coerce')
mydata['player_rating'] = pd.to_numeric(mydata['player_rating'], errors='coerce')
mydata['diff_rating'] = mydata['opponent_rating']-mydata['player_rating']
mydata = mydata[mydata.score >= 0]

avgopprating = mydata['opponent_rating'].mean()
totalpercent = mydata['score'].sum()
averageopponent = mydata['diff_rating'].mean()
myrating = mydata['player_rating'].iloc[0]
lastrating = mydata['player_rating'].iloc[-1]
ratingdiff = myrating - lastrating

mydata = mydata.drop(['event_code', 'event_name', 'club_code', 'org_name', 'section_title', 'opponent_no', 'increment'], axis=1)
mydata.rename(columns = {'opponent_name':'Versus', 'opponent_rating':'Rated', 'player_rating':'NewRating', 'game_date':'Date','colour':'Colour','score':'Score', 'diff_rating':'Diff.'}, inplace = True)
mydata.round(0)
mydata.index.name = "Row"

print(f"Percentage Score: {(100*int(totalpercent)/int(howmanygames)):.0f} %")
print(f"Current Rating: {myrating:.0f}")
print(f"Rating change: {ratingdiff:.0f}")
print(f"Average Opponent Rating: {avgopprating:.0f}")

print(tabulate(mydata, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter Player's (approx.) First Name (e.g Joh for John): jas
Enter Player's (approx.) Last Name (e.g Smi for Smith): ler
+-------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
|   Row | Full_Name    | ECF_code   |   FIDE_no | Club          | Gender   | LastGame   |
|-------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------|
|     0 | LeRoy, Jason | 233382L    |    461512 | North Bristol | M        | 2022-03-17 |
+-------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
Choose Row Number: 0
Enter how many past games you want to see: 10
Percentage Score: 20 %
Current Rating: 1382
Rating change: nan
Average Opponent Rating: 1591
+-------+------------+----------+---------+----------------------+---------+-------------+---------+
|   Row | Date       | Colour   |   Score | Versus               |   Rated |   NewRating |   Diff. |
|-------+------------+----------+---------+----------------------+---------+-------------+---------|
|     0 | 2022-03-17 | B        |     0   | Marston, Alastair JD |    1756 |        1382 |     374 |
|     1 | 2022-03-01 | B        |     1   | Shipp, Arthur        |    1171 |        1384 |    -213 |
|     2 | 2022-02-17 | W        |     0   | Bartram, James       |    1674 |        1379 |     295 |
|     3 | 2022-02-02 | B        |     0.5 | Paines, John L       |    1390 |        1382 |       8 |
|     4 | 2022-01-20 | W        |     0   | Cullen, Gareth       |    1707 |        1382 |     325 |
|     5 | 2022-01-18 | B        |     0.5 | Paton, John G        |    1571 |        1385 |     186 |
|     6 | 2021-12-09 | B        |     0   | Zielinski, Piotr     |    1587 |        1380 |     207 |
|     7 | 2021-10-12 | B        |     0   | Smith, William       |    1787 |        1385 |     402 |
|     8 | 2021-09-30 | B        |     0   | Macarthur, Duncan M  |    1675 |        1387 |     288 |
|     9 | 2020-02-16 | W        |     0   | Daly, Grant          |     nan |         nan |     nan |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+----------------------+---------+-------------+---------+
```

The "Rating Change" calculation returns "nan" - I want it to ignore the "nan"s and compute the calculation as usual for the numbers. Tried many things - nothing seems to work!!

Comment: "Tried many things", you say; What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to ignore the "nan"s and compute the calculation as usual for the numbers.

That sentence is strange...there is a reason for NaN ("Not a Number").

Your problem is somewhere between your data request and the `pandas.to_numeric()` calls. For instance, if `nan` is non-acceptable in your algorithm, you should avoid using `to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')`. See [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for available options.

Also, double-check the answer you're getting from the api (ie., `data`).

Comment: I guess the simple question is that if a pandas dataframe column has a NaN how do you perform operations on the remaining data while ignoring NaN.